# Count how many documents contain a field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have these three MongoDB documents:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("571094afc2bcfe430ddd0815"), 
    "name" : "Barry", 
    "surname" : "Allen", 
    "address" : [
        {
            "street" : "Red", 
            "number" : NumberInt(66), 
            "city" : "Central City"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "Yellow", 
            "number" : NumberInt(7), 
            "city" : "Gotham City"
        }
    ]
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57109504c2bcfe430ddd0816"), 
    "name" : "Oliver", 
    "surname" : "Queen", 
    "address" : {
        "street" : "Green", 
        "number" : NumberInt(66), 
        "city" : "Star City"
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5710953ac2bcfe430ddd0817"), 
    "name" : "Tudof", 
    "surname" : "Unknown", 
    "address" : "homeless"
}
```

The `address` field is an `Array` of Objects in the first document, an `Object` in the second and a `String` in the third.
My target is to find how many documents of my collection containinig the field **`address.street`**. In this case the right count is 1 but with my query I get two:

```
db.coll.find({"address.street":{"$exists":1}}).count()
```

I also tried map/reduce. It works but it is slower; so if it is possible, I would avoid it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The distinction here is that the `.count()` operation is actually "correct" in returning the "document" count where the field is present. So the general considerations break down to:

### If you just want to exlude the documents with the array field

Then the most effective way of excluding those documents where the "street" was a property of the "address" as an "array", then just use the dot-notation property of looking for the `0` index to not exist in the exlcusion:

```js
db.coll.find({
  "address.street": { "$exists": true },
  "address.0": { "$exists": false }
}).count()
```

As a natively coded operator test in both cases `$exists` does the correct job and efficiently.

### If you intended to count field occurences

If what you are actually asking is the "field count", where some "documents" contain array entries where that "field" may be present several times.

For that you need the aggregation framework or mapReduce like you mention. MapReduce uses JavaScript based processing and is therefore going to be considerably slower than the `.count()` operation. The aggregation framework also needs to calculate and "will" be slower than `.count()`, but not by as much as mapReduce.

In MongoDB 3.2 you get some help here by the expanded ability of [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to work on an array of values as well as being an grouping accumulator. The other helper here is [`$isArray`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isArray/) which allows a different processing method via [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) when the data is in fact "an array":

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "count": {
      "$sum": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$isArray": "$address" },
            "then": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$address",
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": { "$ifNull": [ "$$el.street", false ] },
                    "then": 1,
                    "else": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "else": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": { "$ifNull": [ "$address.street", false ] },
                "then": 1,
                "else": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Earlier versions hinge on a bit more conditional processing in order to treat the array and non-array data differently, and generally require [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to process array entries.

Either transposing the array via [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) with MongoDB 2.6:

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "address": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$ifNull": [ "$address.0", false ] },
        "then": "$address",
        "else": {
          "$map": {
            "input": ["A"],
            "as": "el",
            "in": "$address"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$address" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "count": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$ifNull": [ "$address.street", false ] },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or providing conditional selection with MongoDB 2.2 or 2.4:

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "address": { 
      "$first": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$ifNull": [ "$address.0", false ] },
          "$address",
          { "$const": [null] }
        ]
      }
    },
    "other": {
      "$push": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$ifNull": [ "$address.0", false ] },
          null,
          "$address"
        ]
      }
    },
    "has": { 
      "$first": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$ifNull": [ "$address.0", false ] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$address" },
  { "$unwind": "$other" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "count": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [ "$has", 1 ] },
          { "$cond": [
            { "$ifNull": [ "$address.street", false ] },
            1,
            0
          ]},
          { "$cond": [
            { "$ifNull": [ "$other.street", false ] },
            1,
            0
          ]}
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

So the latter form "should" perform a bit better than mapReduce, but probably not by much.

In all cases the logic falls to using [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) as the "logical" form of `$exists` for the aggregation framework. Paired with [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), a "truthfull" result is obtained when the property actually exsists, and a `false` value is returned when it is not. This determines whether `1` or `0` is returned respectively to the overall accumulation via [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

Ideally you have the modern version that can do this in a single [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage, but otherwise you need the longer path.

Comment: This is a great answear. My target is to find the number of occurrences of a field in a collection. At first I was using count() but it didn't work pretty good. Now I'm using a recursive map reduce to count the occurrences. It works but it is slow. I'll try your tips, thank you.

Comment: It works perfectly. But suppose I jave another recursive map reduce that finds all fields present in my collection. For each field I have to count occurrences.
If I don't know the shape of the schema, is it possible to use aggregation to count occurrences, or must I use map reduce?

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana If you have another question then [Ask Another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), since we can only really answer the questions that you directly ask, and it is better to express another question in it's own post where you can place all the detail. The question you actually asked here shows a document structure with consistent paths, and not to mention that only your original question title suggested you actually where trying to count field occurances as the rest of the question body taks about matching documents.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({
        "address.street":{"$exists":1},
        "$where": "Array.isArray(this.address) == false && typeof this.address === 'object'"
});
```

In where clause, we are excluding if address is array and
Including address if it's type is object.

Comment: Though the question title was somewhat misleading, the OP did clearly state that they expected a count of "three" from their data. Which does indicate that the document containing the "array" which has "two" matches would be included in the total. So "two" from the array document, "one" from the document with a single object, and "none" for the document where "street" is not a sub-property of "address". Which is not what the query you submitted here does.

Comment: Actually I think I misread that initially, but there is still a much faster way than using `$where`. Just use `"address.0": { "$exists": false }` in the conditions. Since the `0` index is only present when the field is in fact an "array".